# Numero de revisões por arquivo salvas via Git

Tags: git, versionamento, psd

Tenho uma necessidade muito especifica, preciso armazenar no máximo 3 revisões de um arquivo PSD, sendo que a cada nova revisão a mais antiga é deletada. É possível fazer isso no Git?

Comment: Bruno, Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Sua pergunta não parece estar relacionada com programação. Faça um [tour] para entender quais tipos de perguntas aceitamos por aqui.

Comment: @gmsantos GIT está altamente relacionado a programação, não vejo motivo para não fazer parte do escopo; Bruno, não acho que seja possível, entretanto não tenho certeza, vamos aguardar para ver se alguém consegue uma solução.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de limitar somente a 3 revisões?

Comment: @Math concordo que git faz parte do dia-a-dia dos programadores. Mas nessa pergunta em questão não vejo que versionamento de imagens seja relacionado com programação. Inseri no [meta on-topic](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1998/4751) esse tópico para votação.

Comment: @gmsantos isso não importa muito, porque se ele trocar `.psd` por `.php`, muda alguma coisa na resposta? A resposta então será útil para programadores. As regras não existem para serem levadas ao pé da letra. Temos que ver se terá utilidade para os a nossa audiência. A regra não existe para o bem da regra, existe para o bem da audiência. Sistemas de controle de versão não foram feitos para versionar código mas para versionar arquivos. Por acaso ele está fazendo isto em `.psd`.

Comment: A questão de salvar arquivos de .PSD realmente não faz parte diretamente dos assuntos ligados a programação. Mas o uso do Git, como parte integrante de versionamento de código, e já fazendo parte de ferramentas de programação, como o Xcode, podem ser abordados. 

 Neste caso, o @Bruno Batista, faz referencia do Git, questionando seu suporte a versões de imagens. Não foi solicitado nenhuma informação sobre como editar o PSD, e sim questionou a possibilidade do Git para fatorar suas modificações. 

 Ao meu ponto de vista, parece um tópico útil e de interesse amplo, e condizente com o uso do Git.

Comment: Realmente, olhando pelo ponto de vista da utilidade da resposta faz sentido manter a pergunta . Vou retirar o voto para fechamento.

Comment: Primeiro quero agradecer a todos por tentar me ajudar. Arquivos do photoshop costumam ter tamanho em bites acima de um arquivo normal, fica ruim ter tantos MB salvos. Gostaria de salvar somente as ultimas 3 alterações.

Comment: Estou versionando tanto os fontes (PSD), o frontend (HTML, Imagens, CSS e JS) e o backend (PHP). Dessa forma posso entregar ao cliente todo projeto versionado. A questão em destaque é versionar arquivos de grande porte, e procurar uma maneira de manter poucas revisões do mesmo.

Comment: Bruno, caso a resposta oferecida seja satisfatória, será interessante marca-la como correta para que outras pessoas possam utiliza-la como referência.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até o momento o Adobe Photoshop não apresenta integração com versionamento de arquivos .PSD. Mas acredito que você possa criar uma pasta no Github, e a partir dela fazer um fork, que irá gerar uma cópia ramificada da original, e a cada modificação vc deve salvar o arquivo em um fork diferente. Faça um teste.

Você pode consultar o funcionamento e uso das ferramentas do Github a partir de e-Book gratuito oferecido pelo próprio Git.

http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br

Comment: Agradeço sua explicação. Ainda me resta a duvida se é possível definir um limite de revisões por arquivo. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom, o numero de versões de arquivo é aberto. Mas acredito que isso so será possivel caso você possua um servidor, e o servidor controlar as versoes, e nas suas configurações vc determinar o limite para 3 versoes. Caso nao encontre a solução ou ela seja demasiadamente complexa, acredito que fazer manualmente a copia para um novo segmento de versões será mais satisfatorio.

Comment: Ah, e para marcar que vc aceitou minha resposta acima, abaixo do triangulo laranja, existe um sinal verde (Marcar), para sinalizar como resposta aceita. :D

Comment: Eu sei amigo, estou esperando uma resposta melhor. Agradeço sua ajuda!